# Как удалить одинаковые названия в переменной?

Tags: php

Есть переменная, в ней список картинок через запятую:

```
$string = 'site.com/50b/gdh8ec6267b05384/DSC0565615.jpg, site.com/d70/d709cce76a2b82/DSC05660_16.jpg, 
site.com/81a/81a33d1b802/DSC05662_37.jpg, site.com/7ae/7aee9f0757/DSC05663_38.jpg, 
site.com/be2/be259f17bcbe108/DSC05664_39.jpg, site.com/8ec/8ec62557d67b05384/DSC0565615.jpg, 
site.com/b99/b99e396662dadd03859b3/DSC0566641.jpg';
```

В этом списке 2 раза повторяется DSC0565615.jpg, возможно ли удалить повторы в переменной по названию файла? Должно получится вот так:

```
$string = 'site.com/50b/gdh8ec6267b05384/DSC0565615.jpg, site.com/d70/d709cce76a2b82/DSC05660_16.jpg, 
site.com/81a/81a33d1b802/DSC05662_37.jpg, site.com/7ae/7aee9f0757/DSC05663_38.jpg, 
site.com/be2/be259f17bcbe108/DSC05664_39.jpg, site.com/b99/b99e396662dadd03859b3/DSC0566641.jpg';
```

Comment: это могут быть совсем разные картинки. почему вы например хотите сохранить первую, а не последнюю, что чуть короче по коду

Comment: делите строку по разделителю в массив. Потом цикл: излечение имени файла, и переброска в новый массив, где ключ - имя. собираете результат обратно в строку

Comment: @teran только надо проверять нет ли уже ключа, а то соберется последний, а не первый - о чем я и спросил в комментарии

Comment: @splash58 цикл можно писать в обратную сторону

Comment: В переменной список картинок через запятую, они находятся в разных директориях, но названия файлов всегда одинаковые, например DSC0565615.jpg. Нужно удалить одинаковые файлы из списка и без разницы какой путь будет до картинки, первый или второй. Главное чтобы не было повторов. Нельзя сделать жесткое сравнение по последнему названию файла и вывести результат без повторов?

Comment: алгоритм описан выше. вам понадобятся функции `explode(), basename()` цикл `foreach` а также `implode` для обратного преобразования. Попробуйте реализовать сие самостоятельно

Comment: Я пробовала, но к сожалению ничего не получилось, поэтому и обратилась за помощью :) Буду искать, где то же должно быть подобное))

Comment: @СветланаЗайцева а что именно не получилось из списка выше? разбить строку  по запятым, сделать цикл, собрать обратно?

Comment: Если пробовали, то добавьте к вопросу ваш код.

Comment: Я вывела названия файлов и удалила повторы через implode. Но проблема в том, что не смогла обратно собрать по точному пути.

Comment: @СветланаЗайцева что бы мы могли обсуждать проблемы вашего кода, его надо увидеть. Добавьте в вопрос, покажите, чем результат не устроил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'site.com/50b/gdh8ec6267b05384/DSC0565615.jpg, site.com/d70/d709cce76a2b82/DSC05660_16.jpg, site.com/81a/81a33d1b802/DSC05662_37.jpg, site.com/7ae/7aee9f0757/DSC05663_38.jpg, site.com/be2/be259f17bcbe108/DSC05664_39.jpg, site.com/8ec/8ec62557d67b05384/DSC0565615.jpg, site.com/b99/b99e396662dadd03859b3/DSC0566641.jpg';
    
$result = explode(',', $string);
$new =[];
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $st = basename($value);
    $new[$st] = $value;
}
   
var_dump($new);
```

Comment: Вы мой герой! Спасибо огромное, всё получилось ;)